# Why does string match work on local host and not in web host?

Tags: php, mysql

The following match criteria within an sql statement properly finds last names that start with an A and have an apostrophe when running in my MAMP environment using PHP 5.6.30.

```
"m.last_name LIKE '%A\'%'"
```

However, the identical code in my hosted environment running php 5.3 throws an sql error.

I am assuming the error must have something to do with the php.ini file settings, with regard to escape characters.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction on this?

Comment: Magic quotes? I'm guessing it's something with the single quote

Comment: try with two single quotes when working with "m.last_name LIKE '%A''%'"

Comment: *"throws an sql error."* -- what do you expect from us? To guess what error message you get? Post the error message, post the complete SQL query, post some PHP code if needed to clarify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use tow single quote '' to escape apostrophe(') character.

```
"m.last_name LIKE '%A''%'"
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

We discovered a bug in our code.  We missed updating a module doing a similar search.  My bad!  thanks for the help.